# Reference field from within the same schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema

```js
const mySchema = new Schema({
  limit: Number,
  currentlyAdded: Number
});
```

I want `currentlyAdded` to be at most `limit`.
`max` doesn't seem to accept a function so I can't do `function() { return this.limit }`

Is there a way to somehow reference `limit` field from `currentlyAdded` so I could do something like that

```js
const mySchema = new Schema({
  limit: Number,
  currentlyAdded: {
    type: Number,
    max: %reference_to_limit%
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `validate` property to validate the limit condition by calling a function,

```
const mySchema = new Schema({
  limit: Number,
  currentlyAdded: { 
    type: Number,
    validate: [checkLimit, "Exceeded the limit!"]
  }
});

// CHECK VALIDATION
function checkLimit(currentlyAdded) {
  return currentlyAdded <= this.limit;
}
```